# How to retrieve Jquery post values in PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, http-post

I have a code shown below and test.php file. My question is how to retrieve name and time in the php file?

```
 $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the values will be in $_POST. IN your example `$_POST['name']` will include `John`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `$_POST["name"]` would be `"John"` and `$_POST["time"]` would be `"2pm"`. Similarly, if you had used `$.get` in jQuery, the data would be in `$_GET` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll find the data you've posted to the server in the `$_POST` collection.

Did you try this to find out? What were your results?

Answer (score 0):

Then you can place the response text(something you print in `test.php`) with this code

`$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },function(responseText){//do what you want with variable 'responseText' here});`